# C# Checking a variable against a arrays index?

Tags: c#, arrays

Sorry if the title isnt clear enough, But heres my problem.

so i have this array:

```
public static string[] stringArray = new string[3] {"Menu", "Options", "Exit"};
```

and this variable:

```
public static int pointerLocation = 0;
```

now my end goal is to check if eg if pointerLocation is equal to any index of the array.
to then print > infront of the "selected" item or current index.

My problem is when im checking if `pointerLocation == stringArray[0]` i am of course faced with the problem of not being able to compare string and int's.

So what can i do to work around this?

EDIT:

Heres exactly what im trying to do.
Im trying to create a Menu in the console and i want the user to want to be able to see whats selected so it will look like this:

```
> Start
Options
Exit
```

And i want the > to be printed on the lne where the index of the item in the array is equal to my variable pointerLocation, If that makes sense?

Also the pointerLocation variable will be incrementing/decrementing as the up/down arrows are pressed

Comment: You're actually trying to see if the array has a value at index 0? Or if the array has any items at all?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've updated my post to show what i want better

Comment: Your question still makes no sense.  It sounds like you actually want to compare your variable to `0`.  Try writing actual code and see what happens.

Comment: @SLaks Obviously i have tried. What i want to do is this: When the user presses eg were at index [0] when the user presses up arrow, we go up to [1] and then ">" moves from start to Options.

Comment: How are you drawing the `>`?

Comment: Well using some of the other answers i was able to get this:

public static void printMenu()
        {
            foreach (var menuelement in stringArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> " + stringArray[pointerLocation]);
                
            }
        }

to print out the > but it just loops through menu a load of times and not the full array, Ill continue to work on it though and try

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this will help

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == pointerLocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("> " + stringArray[pointerLocation]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stringArray[pointerLocation]);
    }
}
```

Let me suggest some variable renames

- `stringArray` → `menuItems`
- `pointerLocation` → `selected`

Comment: Updated the OP to explain it better

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the `pointerLocation` index is strictly smaller than the size of the array before accessing it:

```
if (pointerLocation < stringArray.Length)
{
    // You can access and use the value at the specified index safely here
    string value = stringArray[pointerLocation];
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare index of any value in array, so it's simply:

```
public static string[] stringArray = new string[3] {"Menu", "Options", "Exit"};
public static int pointerLocation = 0;
if(pointerLocation==Array.IndexOf(stringArray, "Menu"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(stringArray[pointerLocation]);
}
```

But if array contains more than one values, so function returns only first index of matched values.